# Call a method from the helper class on the page that is calling the helper method

Tags: c#, asp.net, helper

I have 3 ASP.NET pages.  Each has its own *GetSearchResult* method, which produces a different search result and fills a GridView.  Each page calls a shared helper method from a helper class.

Now in this helper class, I want to execute that *GetSearchResult* method that belongs to on the page that called the helper method.

Is this possible?  And if so, how should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in an instance of the class that owns the method GetSearchResult as a parameter to your helper method. This will give the helper method access to the callers methods. You will need to implement an interface to do this.

```
public interface ISearchable
{
    void GetSearchResult();
}

public class MyPage : Page, ISearchable
{
    public void GetSearchResult() {
        HelperClass.HelperMethod(this); // Pass in
    }
}

public static class HelperClass
{
    public static void HelperMethod(ISearchable page) {
        page.GetSearchResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a reference to the page as an argument to the helper method, and call GetSearchResult again on the page. 
(Ideally, your page should implement an interface, say ISearchPage, that contains the method GetSearchResult)

[Edit: as I was typing the above, David Anderson provided code in his answer]

Or, from within your helper method, set a status flag on the helper object (or use an enumeration of statuses). In your page, you could read that flag or enum value and if the status says that GetSearchResult should be called again, call it again.